# How to convert the Powershell cmdlet standard output to other format?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an output like below from PowerShell command line,

```
SNO     Id      ComputerName        Name        LastModifiedBy      State   Priority    Description 
---     --      ------------        ----        --------------      -----   --------    -----------
1       adF     ABCRTC              test        user453             Normal  Low         This is a test activity1
2       arF     ABCRRR              te12        user453             Normal  Low         This is a test activity2
3       afF     ABCREE              te23        user453             Normal  Low         This is a test activity3
4       cdF     ABCRVV              te45        user453             Normal  Low         This is a test activity4
```

I'm trying to convert it into following format, but i'm not getting due to some `spaces` in last column `Description`

```
1;adF;ABCRTC;test;user453;Normal;Low;This is a test activity1
2;arF;ABCRRR;te12;user453;Normal;Low;This is a test activity2
3;afF;ABCREE;te23;user453;Normal;Low;This is a test activity3
4;cdF;ABCRVV;te45;user453;Normal;Low;This is a test activity4
```

I use to work occasionally on PS1, Help me.

Comment: Pipe your output to the following command: `ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: -1 for unclear problem statement. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: care to post the script that you use?

Answer (score 0):

`myInstruction | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Obersht gave the right answer in his comment for the most part. Building off that, to give the exact output that you want you'd have to filter it a bit so as to cut out the header line, and remove any quotes that it injects when it converts it to a CSV. Add this to the end of whatever command you are running that is feeding you output, or pipe an array to it:

```
|ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation|Out-String|%{$_.split("`n")|select -skip 1|%{$_.Replace('";"',';') -replace "(^`"|`"\s*$)"}}
```

That will give you exactly the output that you desire.